# django - 'function' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to learn about class based views and django in general. The project is `notes_project` and in it I have created an app `notes`. Below is the `urls.py` for both of these and `views.py` for `notes` app:

**notes_project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import notes


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'notes_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^notes/', include('notes.urls')),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**notes/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from .views import IndexView


urlpatterns = patterns(r'^$/', IndexView.as_view())
```

**notes/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View


class IndexView(View):

    def get(request):
        return HttpResponse("Welcome to notes index")
```

However, whenever I access the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/, I keep getting below error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute 'resolve'
Exception Location: /path/notes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve, line 345
Python Executable:  /path/notes/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['/path/notes/notes_project',
 '/path/notes/venv/lib/python3.4',
 '/path/notes/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/path/notes/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/path/notes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `patterns` is a string that acts as prefix to the rest of the patterns. Also each pattern needs to be a tuple of its own. You've done that correctly in the main urls.py but missed it in the notes one. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: I've also missed `self` in function definition. Added that, but I still get:

`Using the URLconf defined in notes_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^notes/ ^$/
^grappelli/
^admin/`

Comment: You had an extra `/` at the end of your index pattern, which meant it could never match. I've edited my answer.